# How to create a button with awesome text using link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
=link_to "p", movies_path, :id => dates, class: "fa fa-caret-left"
```

I'm trying to make a button to go back to the home page but display a different data. So I'm want to send a pramas. And it will be a button using the awesome text so it will be a left arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=link_to movies_path, id: dates do 
  <i class = "fa fa-caret-left"></i>
```

if you want to have have the icon inside a button if you're using bootstrap for example you could do this inside your haml

```
= link_to movies_path, id: dates do
  .btn.btn-info 
    %i.fa.fa-caret-left
```

Or reguler html.erb

```
<%= link_to movies_path, id: dates do %>
  <div class="btn btn-info">
    <i class = "fa fa-caret-left"></i>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Obviously make sure you've included font awesome probably with gem https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails

Comment: I have already I can display the font I just can't figure out how to link it

Comment: see updated answer. if you're using HAML the syntax I've provide should work

Comment: "undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/movies":String" i'm getting this error

Comment: also I am using haml. Do I include the <i ></i>?

Comment: figured it out had to take out "p", and just have =link_to movies_path do thank you

Comment: I fixed the haml syntax no need for explicit <i> tag.